# не работает mouseClicked в java

Tags: java, разработка-игр

```
package Game;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class SakuraGame extends JFrame {
static int i = 3;
static Random r = new Random();
private static SakuraGame sakuraGame;
private static Image backGround;
private static Image restart;
private static Image sakura;
private static Image gameOver;
private static long LastFrameTime;
private static float sakura_y = -150;
private static float sakura_x =  (int) (r.nextInt(0,1200));
private static float sakura_v = 200;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    backGround = 
ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("back_ground.jpg"));
    sakura = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("sakura.png"));
    gameOver = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("gameOver.jpg"));
    restart = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("restart.png"));
    sakuraGame = new SakuraGame();
    sakuraGame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    sakuraGame.setResizable(true);
    LastFrameTime = System.nanoTime();
    sakuraGame.setTitle("поймай леписток");
    sakuraGame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GameField gameField = new GameField();
    gameField.getMouseListeners(new MouseAdapter()
    {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            int x = e.getX();
         int y = e.getY();
        float dropXright = sakura_x + sakura.getWidth(null);
        float dropTbotton = sakura_y + sakura.getWidth(null);
        boolean isDrop = x >= sakura_x && x <= dropXright && y <= dropTbotton && y 
>= sakura_y;
        if (isDrop)
        {sakura_x = (int) (r.nextInt(0,1200));
            sakura_y = -100;}
        }
    });
    sakuraGame.add(gameField);
    sakuraGame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void RePaint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, null);
    long corerectTime = System.nanoTime();
    float deltaTime = (corerectTime - LastFrameTime) * 0.000000001f;
    LastFrameTime = corerectTime;
    sakura_y = sakura_y + sakura_v * deltaTime;
    sakura_v = sakura_v + 70;
    g.drawImage(sakura, (int) sakura_x, (int) sakura_y, null);
    if (sakura_y > sakuraGame.getHeight() && i != 0) {
        i--;
        sakura_x = (int) (r.nextInt(0,1200));
        sakura_y = -100;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        g.drawImage(gameOver, -300, -200, null);
        g.drawImage(restart, 1100, 300, null);
    }
}

private static class GameField extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        RePaint(g);
        repaint();
    }
    public void getMouseListeners(MouseAdapter mouseAdapter) {
    }
}
}
```

Всё испробовал, но ничего не помогает.
При нажатии на объект(лепесток) ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно решение некрасивое, но оно работает.

Нам нужно **назначить** mouseListner, а не пытаться его получить. А если и получаете, то там скорее всего Null

Итак для начала опишем отдельный класс для обработчика нажатий по мышке. Следим за импортом классов (везде должно быть awt или swing)

```
   public class ClickListner implements MouseListener {

    private SakuraGame sakuraGame;
    // Это нам понадобится на случай взаимодействия с внешними элементами
    // за пределами класса ClickListner.
    // В вашем случае они все приватные и статические, но чем черт не шутит
    // быть может эта конструкция покажется вам более рациональной.

    public ClickListner(SakuraGame sakuraGame) {
        this.sakuraGame = sakuraGame;
    }

    public void toToSomething(){
        System.out.println("Its work, bro! mouse was clicked!");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        toToSomething();
        // Собственно здесь ловим клик по GameField
        // и дальше делаем что нужно
    }
    
    // Поскольку мы реализуем интерфейс, 
    // контракт должен быть заключен на все методы MouseListener
   

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Изменения в методе main я оставил ваш старый код, закоментив "ненужное".

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // backGround = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("back_ground.jpg"));
            //sakura = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("sakura.png"));
            // gameOver = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("gameOver.jpg"));
            //restart = ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("restart.png"));
            sakuraGame = new SakuraGame();
            sakuraGame.setSize(1920, 1080);
            sakuraGame.setResizable(true);
            LastFrameTime = System.nanoTime();
            sakuraGame.setTitle("поймай леписток");
            sakuraGame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GameField gameField = new GameField();
    //        gameField.getMouseListeners(new MouseAdapter()
    //        {
    //            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    //            {
    //                System.out.println("Catch!");
    //                int x = e.getX();
    //                int y = e.getY();
    //                float dropXright = sakura_x + sakura.getWidth(null);
    //                float dropTbotton = sakura_y + sakura.getWidth(null);
    //                boolean isDrop = x >= sakura_x && x <= dropXright && y <= dropTbotton && y
    //                        >= sakura_y;
    //                if (isDrop)
    //                {sakura_x = (int) (r.nextInt(1200));
    //                    sakura_y = -100;}
    //            }
    //        });
    
            gameField.addMouseListener(new ClickListner(sakuraGame));
// вешаем наш листнер тут.
            sakuraGame.add(gameField);
            sakuraGame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: оставил Фон = ImageIO. прочитайте (СакураГаме. класс. getResourceAsStream ("back_ground.jpg")); sakura=ImageIO.read(SakuraGame.class.getResourceAsStream("сакура. png")); GameOver=ImageIO. read (SakuraGame.class. getResourceAsStream("gameOver.jpg")); перезапуск = ImageIO. read (SakuraGame. class.getResourceAsStream ("перезапуск. png")); и добавил@Переопределить публичную пустоту, выбранную мышью (MouseEvent e) {toToSomething (); Игра.SakuraGame.sakura_x =(int)(Игра.СакураГейм.р. Следующий шаг(0,1200)); Игра.SakuraGame.sakura_y =-100; } но всё ровно при нажатии объект не как не реагирует

Comment: простите за не читабельность прошлого комментария, просто стоит ограничение по символам

Comment: На какой именно объект ? Вы пытались повесить слушатель на gameField, и я показал вам как это сделать. Если вам нужен другой определенный объект, с ним можно сделать то же самое.